# Tool to generate resource profiles (internal resumes) from a central database?

Tags: automation

I'm looking for a tool/service/solution that can automatically generate employee (resource) profiles (which basically looks like resumes) in Microsoft Word or PDF formats from data fed into a central database by the employees.

A profile could include the following data:

Name

- Designation
- Core Competencies e.g., Java, SQL, ANT, MySQL
- Project by project experience with the duration, responsibilities, and tools
  used
- Professional/Education qualifications

The employee profiles need to be approved by the client before allocating an employee to a project.

I'm the resource planner for a tech-startup with 200+ employees. I have a basic knowledge in Microsoft Excel, XML, and DITA. Currently I have to edit/update each profile manually, which takes a lot of time.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does the database exist already, or you want a database recommendation as well? If it exists, you must tell what is its structure.

Comment: Yes. Need a DB recommendation as well.

Comment: As a database, is an Excel file enough? If not, what features do you need?

Comment: Who will maintain the "central database" and how?

Comment: I'm open to anything that does not include creating/editing documents one by one. I don't mind doing the formatting.